# How a CORDA Notary is created

Tags: corda

Could you please let me know how a CORDA Notary is created .
In the gradle file I was able to find the following .

```
deployNodes(){
 name "O=NetworkMapAndNotary,L=London,C=GB"
        notary = [validating : true]
        p2pPort 10002
        cordapps = []
}
```

Is the above only needed step to create a Notary . I searched in the documentation , but was not able to find much details .

So if we want to have multiple notaries , how to configure and wire them together ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial on implementing a custom notary: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-custom-notary.html.

Please note that this is still an experimental feature, and the API is likely to change.